# Display posts from facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have something like this :

```
$config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '';
    $config['secret'] = '';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    $pageid = "";

    // now we can access various parts of the graph, starting with the feed
    $pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed");
```

I want to display more than 25 posts but i don't know how to do it. If someone can help me it will be great.

Comment: “I have 2 questions” Please do not bundle multiple questions together.

Comment: @user2417332: you can [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73754/how-do-i-edit-my-own-question) the question.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve more Posts in your response from Facebook you may use the `limit` parameter and specify the number of Posts you would like to retrieve in the response. So, instead of your current call you may change the same to following

```
$pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed?limit=50");
```

Which will retrieve 50 Posts in the response. The maximum number of result that you can fetch is capped at 5000, which is also mentioned here in the [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/).

Comment: If this solves your problem Please accept it as answer to help others in future